# "Search Paths" is missing in "Build Settings"

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to integrate an external library, and as part of that process created a new NotificationServiceExtension target. As part of the integration process, however, I need to customize the "Search Paths" found in "Build Settings" Tab. Usually this appears directly below the "Linking" section. As you can see in the below screenshot though, nothing's there. [image: Non-existent "Search Paths"]

What do I need to do differently?

Comment: That's it! Thanks Morteza. I'll accept your answer if you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select all instead of basic, At top bar

Answer (score -1):

Select "All" and "Levels"，At top bar.

Comment: question already answered

Comment: Not in " Basic", is "Levels"